# Detecting foreground app name in android

Tags: android, service, foreground

I want to know the foreground app name using my service.

I already used below code but they only give my app name or home.
but unable to get the name when I open facebook messenger or other apps.

here is code that I am using in my service.

```
            ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo result=null, info=null;

                ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) Verifying_Service.this.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
                PackageManager pm1 = Verifying_Service.this.getPackageManager();
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
                for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
                    if(appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                        CharSequence c = null;
                        try {
                            c = pm1.getApplicationLabel(pm1.getApplicationInfo(appProcess.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(Verifying_Service.this, appProcess.processName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Log.i("Foreground App", "package: " + appProcess.processName + " App: " + c.toString());
                    }
                }
```

and  I also tried this one

```
   ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) Verifying_Service.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

// The first in the list of RunningTasks is always the foreground task.
                ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(5).get(0);

                String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo .topActivity.getPackageName();
                PackageManager pm = Verifying_Service.this.getPackageManager();
                PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo = null;
                try {
                    foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

                Toast.makeText(Verifying_Service.this, foregroundTaskAppName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Thank you in advance.
Currently I am using marshmallow android version.

Comment: Apps aren't supposed to care about exactly what other apps are running. From the documentation for `getRunningTasks`: _"this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person information to the caller"_. You may be able to find workarounds on rooted devices, or perhaps by implementing an `AccessibilityService` (but that service would have to be explicitly enabled by the user).

Comment: Google doesn't allow using AccessibilityService for non-accessibility related topics anymore and it could get your app banned. Use the UsageStatsManager instead.

Comment: Hey Thank you @Ch4t4r ...  It works with UsageStatsManager.